# How to do this getTotals() method works?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a finance app and the method getTotals() is responsible for increment or decrement the values of boxes in the high part depending if the user add a income value or expense value but the most recent value is overwritening the older value. Typescript shows the following error message:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, (callbackfn: (previousValue: Obj, currentValue: Obj, currentIndex: number, array: Obj[]) => Obj, initialValue: Obj): Obj', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: { receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }, item: Obj) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: Obj, currentValue: Obj, currentIndex: number, array: Obj[]) => Obj'.
      Types of parameters 'acc' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'Obj' is missing the following properties from type '{ receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }': receitas, despesas, saldo
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: { receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }, currentValue: Obj, currentIndex: number, array: Obj[]) => { receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }, initialValue: { ...; }): { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: { receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }, item: Obj) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: { receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }, currentValue: Obj, currentIndex: number, array: Obj[]) => { receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ receitas: number; despesas: number; saldo: number; }.ts(2769)"
```

Here is my code.

```
private getTotals() {
        this.valores.reduce((acc, item) => {
            if (item.checked === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-up arrowUp-icon"></i>') {
                acc.receitas += item.valor
                acc.saldo += item.valor
            } else if (item.checked === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-down arrowDown-icon"></i>') {
                acc.despesas += item.valor
                acc.saldo -=  item.valor
            }
            this.receitas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(acc.receitas)
            this.despesas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(acc.despesas)
            this.saldo.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(acc.saldo)
        }, {receitas: 0, despesas: 0, saldo: 0})
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your error message's point is `reduce`

`reduce` needs callbackfn like

```js
(previousValue: Obj, currentValue: Obj) => Obj
```

but your code uses

```js
(previousValue: Obj, currentValue: Obj) => void
```

so correct code must be like...

```js
private getTotals() {
        const res = this.valores.reduce((acc, item) => {
            if (item.checked === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-up arrowUp-icon"></i>') {
                acc.receitas += item.valor
                acc.saldo += item.valor
            } else if (item.checked === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-down arrowDown-icon"></i>') {
                acc.despesas += item.valor
                acc.saldo -=  item.valor
            }
            return acc
        }, {receitas: 0, despesas: 0, saldo: 0})

        this.receitas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(res.receitas)
        this.despesas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(res.despesas)
        this.saldo.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(res.saldo)
    }
```

This much makes sense for me.

Why you try to set something in loop?

In most cases, setting a result value is enough.